# Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

> Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I am getting this error in VS 2015, when i am executing the application.
The application earlier it was in **VS 2013** there is no error.

Comment: Try to install the latest EF or version 5.0.0 specifically.

Comment: Try to install EntityFramework `Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 5.0.0`

Comment: @Div - i had updated the Entityframework package like update-Package EntityFramework. if it is wrong let me know.

Comment: @user3259635 *if it is wrong let me know* did not get you!

Comment: @Div - Can i update the Entity framework package like this also right - update-Package EntityFramework.

Comment: Yes, you can. that is also right way

Comment: @Div -- Thank you

Comment: If you are still facing the issue, try installing the EF 5 version using NuGet again (Right click the project and use Manage NuGet packages).

Answer (score 1):

Open Package Manager Console and try to install EF.

```
Toos > Nuget Package Manager > Package Manager Console
```

Run

```
PM> install-package entityframework -version 5.0.0.0
```

Or you can update it to latest version(version 6.1.2) using below command

```
PM> Update-Package entityframework
```

Comment: @Div- Once i installed Entity framework tried to execute the application getting error like this 
Line 130:      </parameters>
Line 131:    </defaultConnectionFactory>
Line 132:    <providers>
Line 133:      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
Line 134:    </providers>

Comment: This is not actual error, this is only line number and code which gives an error, add your error!

Comment: @Div-An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception. this an error Occured while running

Comment: @user3259635, This may be cause of your app.config file hold older version of EF, Please check it, and update it with current version

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. My project's had EF version 6.0, I tried made scaffolding MVC with ef 5.0 and razor views and received this error. I made stop IIS for this web site, clear solution, rebuild solution, fix error, rebuild solution successfuly. Then a try again (make mvc ef scaffolding) and my problem resolved