# Convert Task<decimal> to decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm getting this error when I try to convert `Task<decimal>` to `decimal`:

> Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Here is my method:

```
public async Task<decimal> GetTotalProposalAmount()
{
    using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
    {
        var total = db.Database.SqlQuery<decimal>("Get_ProposalTotal", null);
        return await total.FirstAsync();
    }
}
```

I'm calling it here in the controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int? page, string search)
{

   model.Proposaltotal = Convert.ToDecimal(GetTotalProposalAmount());
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Read the Warnings: Index() is not awaiting anything.

Comment: your error has nothing to do with Task and Async... your just using  it incorrectly but that's not why your getting an error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You simply have to await the task:

```
model.Proposaltotal = await GetTotalProposalAmount();
```

This has nothing to do with your build error though, [just add the reference it asks for](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39530638/993547).